# TestNG using multiple DataProviders with single Test method

Tags: java, testing, automation, testng

I have been looking for a way to use multiple DataProviders in my test method. My scenario is as follows:

lets say we have a DataProvider class:

```
@Test
public class ExampleDataProvider {

   /**
     * Returns the list of shape codes.
     * 
     * @return the collection shape codes.
     */
    @DataProvider(name = "ShapeCodes")
    public static Object[][] getShapeCodes() {
        return new Object[][] { new Object[] { Shape.Square }, 
            new Object[] { Shape.Triangle }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Returns the list of color codes.
     * 
     * @return the collection of color codes.
     */
    @DataProvider(name = "ColorCodes")
    public static Object[][] geColorCodes() {
        return new Object[][] { new Object[] { Color.Green }, 
            new Object[] { Color.Red }
        };
    }
}
```

Now in my Test method I want to run for all combinations of scenarios:

1. Green-Square
2. Red-Square
3. Green-Triangle
4. Red-triangle

How should I achieve this in my code, given that I cant specify multiple DataProviders with `@Test` annotation

```
@Test(dataProvider = "ShapeCodes", dataProviderClass = ExampleDataProvider.class)
    public void test(String ShapeCode, String ColorCode) throws IOException {
        .............
        /* tests for color shape combination */
        .............
    }
```

EDIT : I found a similar problem and a @ [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525989/several-dataprovider-per-one-test-in-testng?rq=1) but I am still wondering if there are better ways to handle this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the lack of a better approach, I decided to stick to the workaround. here is an example of how the above scenario could be implemented:

```
@Test
public class ExampleDataProvider {

   /**
     * Returns the list of shape codes.
     * 
     * @return the collection shape codes.
     */
    @DataProvider(name = "ShapeCodes")
    public static Object[][] getShapeCodes() {
        return new Object[][] { new Object[] { Shape.Square }, 
            new Object[] { Shape.Triangle }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Returns the list of color codes.
     * 
     * @return the collection of color codes.
     */
    @DataProvider(name = "ColorCodes")
    public static Object[][] geColorCodes() {
        return new Object[][] { new Object[] { Color.Green }, 
            new Object[] { Color.Red }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Returns the list object codes providing a color shape combination.
     * 
     * @return the collection of object codes.
     */
    @DataProvider(name = "objectCodes")
    public static Object[][] getObjectCodes(){
        return combine(geColorCodes(),  getShapeCodes());
    }


    /**
     * Returns the list of combination of color and shape codes.
     * 
     * @return the collection of combined color and shape codes.
     */
    public static Object[][] combine(Object[][] a1, Object[][] a2){
        List<Object[]> objectCodesList = new LinkedList<Object[]>();
        for(Object[] o : a1){
            for(Object[] o2 : a2){
                objectCodesList.add(concatAll(o, o2));
            }
        }
         return objectCodesList.toArray(new Object[0][0]);
    }


    @SafeVarargs
    public static <T> T[] concatAll(T[] first, T[]... rest) {
     //calculate the total length of the final object array after the concat    
      int totalLength = first.length;
      for (T[] array : rest) {
        totalLength += array.length;
      }
      //copy the first array to result array and then copy each array completely to result
      T[] result = Arrays.copyOf(first, totalLength);
      int offset = first.length;
      for (T[] array : rest) {
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, result, offset, array.length);
        offset += array.length;
      }

      return result;
    }
}
```

This way I get to use my Color codes and Shape codes separately and also provides me to use the combination.

So, my test methods would look like:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "objectCodes", dataProviderClass = ExampleDataProvider.class)
     public void test(String ShapeCode, String ColorCode) throws IOException {
           .............
           /* tests for color shape combination */
           .............
          }

@Test(dataProvider = "ShapeCodes", dataProviderClass = ExampleDataProvider.class)
    public void test(String ShapeCode) throws IOException {
        .............
        /* tests for  shapes */
        .............
    }

@Test(dataProvider = "ColorCodes", dataProviderClass = ExampleDataProvider.class)
    public void test(String ColorCode) throws IOException {
        .............
        /* tests for colors */
        .............
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Great answer Segmented

Maybe someone will need it too, I rewrote this method in a different way.

```
// public static <T> T[] concatAll(T[] first, T[]... rest) {

public static Object[] concat(Object[] first, Object[] second) {
        Object[] result = ArrayUtils.addAll(first, second);
        return result;
```

Comment: You'll need to import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59993761/5016494

This may help

```
    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] combinedDataProvider() {
        return Stream.of(dp1(), dp2())
                .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                .toArray(Object[][]::new);
    }
```