# How to use multiple data provider in single test method

Tags: java, selenium, testng

The Test scenario is -
I have one excel Sheet with multiple sheet. 
I have to use multiple sheet data in one test method.
I have created multiple data generators but don't know how to use multiple data generator in same test method.

Data Generator is below:

```
@DataProvider(name = "Excel")
public static Object[][] testDataGenerator()
        throws Exception {
    ExcelHelper excelManager = new ExcelHelper();
    List<HashMap<String, String>> dataFromFile = excelManager.readSheet(
            TEST_DATA,"Automation");

    Object[][] data = new Object[dataFromFile.size()][1];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i][0] = dataFromFile.get(i);
    }       

    return data;
}
@DataProvider(name = "Excel1")
    public static Object[][] testDataGenerator1()
            throws Exception {    
        ExcelHelper excelManager = new ExcelHelper();
        List<HashMap<String, String>> dataFromFile = excelManager.readSheet(
                TEST_DATA,"Automation1");    
        Object[][] data = new Object[dataFromFile.size()][1];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i][0] = dataFromFile.get(i);
        }       

        return data;
    }
```

Test method is below:

```
  @Test(dataProvider = "Excel", dataProviderClass = DataGenerators.class, priority = 0)
    public void sampleTest(HashMap<String, String> testData){
xyz
}
```

Comment: What is difference in both DataProvider with Scenario ? How many parameters it contains ?

Comment: Why just not loop providers?

Comment: this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549443/testng-using-multiple-dataproviders-with-single-test-method

Comment: I have one parent worksheet. In which there is row for each child worksheet. If the column value of parent worksheet is yes then go to the worksheet and read data.